# Is there always $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $g^{k+1} \equiv g^k+1 \pmod p$, where $p$ is a prime number?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

Let g be a generator of the group $\Bbb Z_p^*$. Show that there is a $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $g^{k+1} \equiv g^k+1 \pmod p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Excuse me please for bad interpretation of my problem for the first time. I was thinking as follows:

$g^{k+1} \equiv g^k+1 \pmod p$ is equivalent to $g^{k+1}-g^k\equiv 1 \pmod p$, which can be rewrite as $(g-1)g^{k}\equiv 1 \pmod p$. I have tried to find solutions in $\Bbb Z_{11}^*$, where the generators are $2,6,7,8$. Then the solutions are:

If $g=2$ then $k=10.n$ ($n \geq 0$); if $g=6$ then $k=10.n+4$;if $g=7$ then $k=10.n+3$; if $g=8$ then $k=10.n+1$.

The coefficient $10n$ is clear from theorem, that for any $a \in \Bbb Z_p^*: a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Therefore we must find a solution of $(g-1)g^k = 1, k < p-1$ to prove the equation above. I have figured out, that if $g$ is not any of $\Bbb Z_p^*$ generators, the solution may not exist. Specific thing about generators is that they generates the whole group..But how can I prove that for generators, the solution must exist?

Comment: Source? Reason for interest? Your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Does $p$ have to be an odd prime here?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! An old-timer's tip: It is advisable to not just paste a question without any context and your own thoughts. After all, this looks, sounds, walks and talks like a homework problem, and may be treated as such by some irritable members. That in turn may cause  your fine and interesting question to attract all kinds of negative attention, downvotes and such. Please edit the question body with this in mind. I am voting to put this *on hold* as an indication that the question is in need of this kind of improvement.

Comment: Note that posting homework problems here is quite ok. As long as you are frank about it, and include your thoughts. If you are totally stuck I suggest that you try and figure out what happens to the difference $g^{k+1}-g^k$ when you increase $k$ by one.

Comment: What are all those vertical bars supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $G = ({\bf Z }/p{\bf Z})^*$. Because $g$ is its generator, the set $\{g^k | k \in {\bf Z } \}$ equals the underlying set of $G$.

Now, because $G$ is a group, left multiplication by any of its elements acts as a permutation on $G$. In particular, because $g \neq 1$ we have that $g - 1 \in G$, so multiplication by $g-1$ acts this way. Therefore the set $\{(g-1)g^k| k \in {\bf Z} \}$ is in bijection with $G$ and, in particular, contains $1$.